# Hooke's law and derivation of work done by spring confusion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, work, integration, spring

For simplicity I'll do this in 1 direction so I can let the sign dictate direction and ditch the vector notation.

The force done by a spring can be written as $$F = -k\Delta x    , $$however this simplifies to $$F=-kx$$ if we are starting from equilibrium ($x_i = 0$) but the force required from some already stretched/compressed (i.e. $x_i \ne 0$), then $$F=-k(x_f-x_i) = -k\Delta x.$$

To calculate the work for said spring, $W=\int F(x) dx $,   which I'm all aboard at however when calculating the work the force always seems to be the "simplified" version from equilibrium with $x$ and not the $\Delta x$ version.  And this causes problems... I think.

To find the work required in stretching/compressing a spring from some initial to some final state.

$W= \int_{x_i}^{x} Fdx$    However if you use $F=-kx$

$W=\int (-kx)dx = -\frac{1}{2}kx^2 \rvert_{x_i}^{x} = -\frac{1}{2}k(x^2-x_i^2) =-\frac{k}{2}\Delta (x^2) $

However going from $x_i \ne 0$ says I can't use that simplified version, so I should use $F = -k\Delta x $

$W=\int -k \Delta x dx = \int-k(x - x_i) dx = -\frac{1}{2}kx^2 \rvert_{x_i}^{x} - (-k)x_i x \rvert_{x_i}^{x} $

$W= -k(\frac{1}{2}(x^2 - x_i^2)-({x_i}{x} - x_i^2)) = -\frac{k}{2}((x^2 - x_i^2)-2({x_i}{x} - x_i^2))$

$W=-\frac{k}{2} (x^2 - x_i^2 -2x_i x +2x_i^2) =-\frac{k}{2}(x^2-2x_ix +x_i^2) = -\frac{k}{2}(\Delta x)^2$

Which is different than the above, now sure if you're talking about a relaxed position $x_i = 0$ then they do equal each other, but if your spring is already stretched or compressed by some amount such that  $x_i \ne 0$ then they most definitely do not add up.

Now I know based on the idea that the integral is the area "under the curve" that the first one is correct, super easy to see with triangles, but what makes the second version incorrect?  Part of me thinks it's because you still have to count the amount of force to go from some equilibrium state to $x_i$ when dealing with work but I don't know how to properly phrase that.

Comment: What do you mean by "but the force required from some already stretched/compressed [spring is] $F=-k(x_f- x_i)$"? This doesn't really make sense.  If the spring is stretched or compressed by an amount $x-x_{0} = x$ (since you're taking the equilibrium position to be 0), then the force acting on the object at that point is $F = - kx$, full stop.  There's no such thing as "initial" and "final" positions when you're talking about the force. There's only a force *at* a particular position. I *think* this might be the result of your confusion. You get to use $F=-kx$ no matter what, here.

Comment: Could be right on where my confusion lie.   I was just thinking of a situation where if there some mass resting on a vertical spring, such that it is compressed,  and I apply a force to compress it a bit more, how much work would I be doing.

Comment: Sure: it requires more *work* to compress by $\Delta x$ when it has already been compressed, but that doesn't change the expression for the *force* that is exerted.

Answer (score 1):

*The force required from some already stretched/compressed*, has the same form. In other words, $F$ is also $kx$, in this condition. $x_i$ is not just the initial point, it is the equilibrium point.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the most generic case: say your equilibrium position is $x_{\text{eq}}$ and that you want to compute the work done by stretching/compressing from position $x_1$ to position $x_2$. We have
$$
  W
  = - k \int_{x_1}^{x_2} (x - x_{\text{eq}}) d x
  = - k \left[\frac{1}{2} x^2 - x x_{\text{eq}}\right]_{x_1}^{x_2}
  = - \frac{k}{2} \left[(x_2^2 - x_1^2) - 2 (x_2 - x_1) x_{\text{eq}}\right].
$$
Now, sum and subtract $x_{\text{eq}}^2$ inside the square braket.
You get
$$
  W
  = - \frac{k}{2} \left[(x_2 - x_{\text{eq}})^2 - (x_1 - x_{\text{eq}})^2\right]
$$
which is exactly what you wanted.

Now, consider the case in which $x_1 = x_{\text{eq}}$.
You get
$$
  W
  = - \frac{k}{2} (x_2 - x_{\text{eq}})^2
$$
which is your second result, the one you claim to be wrong (which evidently it is not.)

Summarizing, both your results are correct.
You were misled by the second because you used the equilibrium position as one of the integration limits, and this confused you.
Besides this, the rest looks good.